# Send mail merge from a distribution group

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

Is it possible to send a mail merge from Word 2007 from a distribution group such as sales@domain.com? The specific user is setup under exchange 2010 to send on "behalf" of this group but I can't find the option to achieve a mail merge. The from field would have to say Sales instead of Username.

Cheers.

Comment: Aside from the actual mail merge itself (which I can't really speak to), you're looking for "Send As" permission, not "Send on Behalf Of". Granting "Send on Behalf Of" permission isn't enough to allow another use to actually send *as* your "Sales@..." address.

Comment: I had added that permission, just called it send on behalf.